# jQuery, $.load doesn't work in webkit and opera?

Tags: jquery, webkit, google-chrome, opera

I'm trying to load an external document using jQuery, $.load call. It seems to work in IE6, IE8 and Firefox 3.5, but it doesn't work in Opera and Webkit browsers (Chrome and Epiphany)... all of them report (in their developer consoles) that they load external document successfully, but they don't show its content.

Test case is here: http://artenis.kirc.pl/jShow-hei6Heix/ (it should show 'Works!').

I guess I am missing something trivial here; I googled a bit but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're not waiting for`$(document).ready()` to me, unless I'm missing something.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var basedir = $("meta[name=basedir]").attr("content");

  function loadslides() {
    $("#presentation").load(basedir+"/slides.html .slide");
  };

  loadslides();
});
```